# Using Pandas with PyQt5. Upon button clicked take the info and load it to the screen

Tags: python, pandas, qt, web-scraping, pyqt

So I have a basic app with a convert button.  Currently with my input I am accepting a URL and scrapping it for the tables (data[2]).  In my function I want to paste this data on my window app when I click my 'convert' button but am getting this error

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QLabel(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'DataFrame'
  QLabel(str, parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'DataFrame'
```

How can I get this to work?

```
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit, QWidget
app = QApplication([])
WIN = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
WIN.setWindowTitle('Table')
WIN.setGeometry(100,100,500,500)
# 
url = input('Paste URL here: ')
data = pd.read_html(url)

date_grid = data[2]
print(date_grid)
# airlines = data['Airlines'].tolist()
# destinations = data['Destinations'].tolist()

text_box = QLineEdit()
label = QLabel('Paste a URL to convert to Excel')
convert_button = QPushButton('Convert')

layout.addWidget(label, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
layout.addWidget(text_box, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
layout.addWidget(convert_button, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
WIN.setLayout(layout)

text_box.setFixedHeight(35)
text_box.setFixedWidth(300)


def covert_btn():
    text = QLabel(date_grid)
    layout.addWidget(text, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
    WIN.setLayout(layout)


convert_button.clicked.connect(covert_btn)

# 
WIN.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: It seems quite clear: `date_grid` is ***not*** a string, nor it can be easily converted to that type. Now, the question is, what do you *actually* want to display on that label?

Comment: @JoshWenner can you share the URL please

Comment: just any basic url from wikipedia for example.  Each wiki page has tables built into it so take this one for example 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnam_Airlines'.  My code currently gets the main information table data (data[2]) and loads it in the terminal as expected.  But I want to take if from the terminal and make it appear on the pyqt5 app window when the button is clicked

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar

Comment: @musicamante here

Comment: @JoshWenner "just any basic url" doesn't make any sense. An "url" can point out to a simple text, an HTML page, a dynamic script or a binary file (image, executable, etc.). A QLabel just shows *text*, it can eventually display HTML using the [limited subset](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) it provides. As the error clearly shows, `DataFrame` is ***not*** a string, so it cannot even be interpreted as HTML. If you don't understand the difference between HTML code and abstract representation of its contents, then I strongly urge you to do some serious research on both of them.

Comment: @JoshWenner your code works fine for me, for the given url

Comment: asking for url with `input()` is missleading.

Comment: `DataFrame` has function `.to_string()` to get it as `string` (like in console), and it also has `.to_html()` to get it as `HTML`

Answer (score 0):

`QLabel` needs `string` with `plain text` or with `HTML`.

`DataFrame` has function `.to_string()` to get it as string (like in console),

```
text = QLabel( date_grid.to_string() )
```

and it also has `.to_html()` to get it as `HTML`

```
text = QLabel( date_grid.to_html() )
```

---

**to_string()**

[image]

**to_html()**

[image]